# Parse arbitrarily deep xml using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an XML file using an XSL file.

My problem is, that my XML file can hold arbitrarily deep path f.x.

```
<document>
    <branch>
        <data>somedata</data>
        <children>
            <branch>
                <data>somedata</data>
                <children>
                    ....
                </children>
            </branch>
         </children>
     </branch>
</document>
```

I don't know the depth of these nodes, but i know how they are named. How do i extract the content of every  node f.x.?

I want to preserver the Hierarchy of the nodes.

Thanks.

I found a solution. Don't know if this is what either Martin og HashCoder meant:

```
<xsl:template match="branch">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="branchcontent.list/branchtext/properties.list/p/@v"/></p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="subbranches.list"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me.. are you trying to copy all of the node values?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am trying to extract the values of the data-elements, and then parse it to an html where they keep the hierarchy in a bulletpoint list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to flatten the hierarchy use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//data"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

If you want to traverse and preserve the hierarchy use

```
<xsl:template match="branch">
  <div>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Regarding the bottom answer: For every branch element in the xml file, you return the content of the data tag? Is that how the code should be read?

Comment: You have not explained which type of result you want (XML, HTML,, plain text). Assuming HTML the second approach creates a HTML `div` result element for any `branch` element and processed the child nodes with matching templates, which are a template for `data` elements creating a text node and a built-in template for other elements keeping up with the recursion.